# how to create setOnClickListener in setText multiple?

Tags: android

here I want to continue the previous question:
[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616204/how-to-make-a-layout-post-group-like-in-a-facebook-android)

how to get setText multiple in **onBindViewHolder** for **setOnClickListener**?

this is my code using **1 TextView** for get name and name group

i want get

```
viewHolder.textView.setText(exampleUtil.getExampleName1() + "" + exampleUtil.getExampleName2);
```

for setOnClickListener name and group

- ExampleName1 for link setOnClickListener for (Name)
- ExampleName2 for link setOnClickListener for (Group)

My source in Adaptor.java :

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
   final ExampleAdaptor.ViewHolder exampleHolder= new ExampleAdaptor.ViewHolder(view);

   exampleHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         how get setText multiple in onBindViewHolder for setOnClickListener?

        }
    });

   return exampleHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final ExampleUtil exampleUtil =  exampleUtils.get(position);
    viewHolder.textView.setText(exampleUtil.getExampleName1() + "" + exampleUtil.getExampleName2);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return exampleUtils.size();
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     public TextView textView;
     public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTop) ;
  }
}
```

If I only use **exampleHolder.textView.setOnClickListener**, the name and group name will be the same if I click the link, I want the name and group to be different click the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpannableString in android to implement such multiple clicks. Here is an example :-

```
SpannableString publishingDetailsSpannable = new SpannableString(finalString);
ClickableSpan platformClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View widget) {
               //Action to perform on click of that part of string
            }
            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
               //To remove underline or other UI features
            }
        };
        publishingDetailsSpannable.setSpan(platformClickableSpan, (start index of the part of the string), (end index of the part of the string), SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```